# img src SYSTEMDRIVE

Tags: php, html, path

It is possible in Html or PHP use drive leter in src like %SYSTEMDRIVE% ?

i need to do something like

```
<img src=%SYSTEMDRIVE%/1.jpg ....
```

And how to detect current user name (means by the HTML or PHP) like %USERPROFILE% in windows?

Comment: well if the user is in a session when the add/edits the image you can get the name from the session like so : $name=$_SESSION['name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of environments like %USERPROFILE% with the `$_ENV` superglobal. So, for instance, `$_ENV['USERPROFILE']` should give you the value of %USERPROFILE%.